# How to make java application create a table one time in the main method

Tags: sql, jdbc, derby

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    Class.forName(DRIVER);
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
    connection.createStatement().execute("create table questions(grade varchar(20), subject varchar(20), question varchar(20), A varchar(1), B varchar(1), C varchar(1), D varchar(1))");
```

this is the code I am working with, essentially I want to execute the createStatement() if the table doesn't exist yet, but if it exists continue. I am not really sure how to reference the table that has been created from within the source code.

Comment: The 'better' (but more complex) way would be to use a database migration library like Flyway or Liquibase. You can also check if your database has conditional DDL, and otherwise you could consult the `DatabaseMetaData` (specifically `getTables`) to check if a table exists or not.

Comment: You can either (a) check before you try to create the table, to see if it already exists. Or, (b) try to create the table, and catch the "table already exists" exception. Do you have a reason to prefer one or the other? Update your question accordingly, and people can suggest improvements more precisely.

Comment: This works perfectly, I was just looking for 'better' ideas, or maybe a more 'standard' way to do this when working with databases. It sounds like much of what I was already thinking is the best way to handle this. This works for be, I will just catch the exception in my code.